# How to Use View.isInEditMode() in custom views to skip code?

Tags: xml, layout, android-custom-view

I'm using a custom view to show gradient color filled TextView as bellow:

```
public class GradientTextView extends TextView {
public GradientTextView(Context context) {
    super(context, null, -1);
}

public GradientTextView(Context context,
                        AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, -1);
}

public GradientTextView(Context context,
                        AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        GradientTextView.getTextColor(context, null, defStyle);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed,
                        int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if (changed) {
        getPaint().setShader(new LinearGradient(
                0, 0, 0, getHeight(),
                Color.parseColor(Color.WHITE), Color.parseColor(Color.BLACK),
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
    }
}
```

}

It works finely on device or emulator but I get Rendering Problem in xml previewer of Android studio which suggests using  View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE and shows this error stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can anyone please help me over this?

Answer (score 2):

[View.isInEditMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isInEditMode%28%29):

> Indicates whether this View is currently in edit mode. A View is usually in edit mode when displayed within a developer tool...

Here's what your custom view Layout file might look like:

```
<com.example.android.customviews.GradientTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And your corresponding view class:

```
package com.example.android.customviews;

public class GradientTextView extends TextView {

    public GradientTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public GradientTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, -1);
    }

    public GradientTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            GradientTextView.getTextColor(context, null, defStyle);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed,
                            int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        if (changed) {
            getPaint().setShader(
                    new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(),
                            Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: I left out your other constructors but see how in the provided constructor I wrap up stuff in a `isInEditMode()` check.

Comment: Tnx, Not actually sure to see what you've changed in the code? Anyway the porblem persists

Comment: Please note that I omitted your first two constructors as they appeared redundant. If you must have them, chain them as I have edited above.

Comment: You'll also need to provide a meaningful default `defStyle` as the `-1` seems from my testing to be root of your `NullPointerException`